# linux and python sed command warning

Tags: linux, sed, terminal, python3

When I run `sed` command in my terminal, it works totally fine; however, when I use it on python, throws an error.

`sed` command:

```
sed ':a; $!N; /^>/!s/\n\([^>]\)/\1/; ta; P; D' test.fasta

SJL19094 
MQVHPTLVLNPKLTIFLSFDGALGGLYDFITPNASALWAPPLGSNRVMYLRSDLRYGDDDPLSWPQSYVPQYCHFPIIRSVLLNPSDSHPDARYTGFRAKLTSTKLILPANAGVQDSYSIISFAWFQKRVDKTVEHGKGTTFFEGAEDLKHSYTVLLHDLLERLQHLPMS
SJL19095 
MGIQAHLGHPQATGEPSGEVWGP
SJL19096 
MLPKEIDEFKNEIDSRGGYMYTLATSINDFTENTHETVCQFLKAAPLIPDLEYKFDPNKREDYPEKQWTSSGLVQDERLSHVRTWLRNVRYHPEGLNNKQYLTFKQYCRNFFLDKEG
SJL19097
MGNGIATSYFQELEMEAKLARRHYDKRERGMMMKAVQLGIPKSYSKFIAMMGFNMPHTYQEWKARVTATYEERQKKWVFDQTTSTPYDSCPLNKGHSNTALATKQMARPPMTAIYKTSNSVS
```

However, using the same code in python gives the following warning.

Python command

```py
import subprocess
command=(f"sed ':a; $!N; /^>/!s/\n\([^>]\)/\1/; ta; P; D' test.fasta")
subprocess.call(single_line,shell=True)
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
```

Any explanation regarding the same would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you're being thwarted by not escaping your "\n" and therefore getting an actual carriage return there.  might try doubling your backslash to escape that one backslash.

Comment: ... possibly also need to double the backslash on the backsubstitution `\\1` as well (since it appears to treat `\1` as byte value `0x1` otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Change your f-string to also include raw strings so that the escape sequence `\n` be taken literally and not expanded, which is what is happening bcoz of which sed is carping. Basically the \n is expanded and sed sees a dead end in the lhs of the s/// command.

The below should get you up n running I believe.

```
command=(fr"sed ':a; $!N; /^>/!s/\n\([^>]\)/\1/; ta; P; D' test.fasta")
```

P. S. Not sure what is the python variable "single_line", but you need the variable "command" in its place.